# Call Virtual Function for Specific Class on Object in C++

Tags: c++

I need to call a function from "declaration" type on some object from outside the class. I did a small code sample and put as comments the desired behavior as I don't know exactly how to ask this:)

```
template<typename T>
void hun(T* obj, class C* c)
{
    //do some checking on c
    if(some conditions from c are true)
    {
        //call fun from T ignoring it's virtual
    }
}

struct A
{
    virtual void fun(){};
    virtual void gun(class C* c)
    {
        //do something specific to A
        hun(this, c); //here call fun from A even if real type of this is B
    };
}

struct B : public A
{
    void fun(){};
    void gun(class C* c)
    {
        //do something specific to B
        hun(this, c);//here call fun from B even if real type of this is something derived from B
    };
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

I know I can call `fun()` from inside the class using `A::fun()` or `B::fun()`, but the checking from `hun()` is common for all classes and I don't want to pollute `gun()` with this code.

Comment: Are you mean obj->T::fun() ?

Comment: @A.Danesh yes:) I didn't knew this is possible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(This has probably been already answered somewhere else..)

You can explicitly call one override of a virtual function using a qualified-id. A qualified-id for a member function is of the form `my_class::my_function`.

For reference, see C++ Standard [expr.call]/1:

> If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in the class
>   member access expression is a qualified-id, that function is called. Otherwise, its final overrider (10.3) in the
>   dynamic type of the object expression is called.

Example

```
template<typename T>
void hun(T* obj, class C* c)
{
    //do some checking on c
    if(some conditions from c are true)
    {
        //call fun from T ignoring it's virtual
        obj->T::fun(); // T::fun is a qualified-id
    }
}

struct A
{
    virtual void fun(){};
    virtual void gun(class C* c)
    {
        //do something specific to A
        hun(this, c); //here call fun from A even if real type of this is B
    };
}; // note: semicolon was missing

struct B : public A
{
    void fun(){};
    void gun(class C* c)
    {
        //do something specific to B
        hun(this, c);//here call fun from B even if real type of this is something derived from B
    };
};
```

Comment: @DyP Yes, this is a very important technique.  This is especially important when the code is part of your bottleneck and you need to tweak it.  A function call made via its full-qualified function name is never made virtual.  This means that you don't have to do a slightly more expensive virtual function call, but the most important part means that it becomes a candidate for inlining.  Inlining doesn't just prevent the function call overhead, it introduces *many* new optimization opportunities for the compiler,  albeit at the expense of (usually but not always) larger code.

Comment: Would `obj->T::fun()` work in C++98? Or is that new in C++11?

Comment: @AlexisWilke This is probably even older than C++98: There is an example similar to `T::fun()` (where `this` is implicitly added to form `this->T::fun()`) in [D&E](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html), which is from 1994.