# Ways to call a member function in C++

Tags: c++

From a long time ago I thought I read I could call a method of an instance of an object using the class name and passing the object in. Ex:

```
classNamw::methodName(classInstance, args)
```

What is the correct syntax for this? I was re-reading C++ documentation but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: you can call a static method like this, but thats not "a method of an instance"

Comment: This is a hack counting on `this` being passed as a hidden first parameter. While this is a common implementation detail, C++ doesn't say how `this` gets into the method, could be teleported by level 7 Elf Magic for all the Standard cares, so this trick is not guaranteed by the C++ Standard. The correct syntax is `classInstance.methodName(args)`

Comment: C++ documentation won't tell you this, because it has never worked like that.  Your recollection is faulty.

Comment: Technically, you can explicitly state the class name like this: `classInstance.className::methodName(args)` but this is rarely used - mostly to call overridden method from super class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253248/call-virtual-function-for-specific-class-on-object-in-c

Comment: I'd guess what you're remembering is an explanation about how calls to member functions are typically implemented (`this` is passed as a "hidden" parameter). While I hesitate to say that it's impossible to do the same on your own, its's not something that's actually supported (and in some calling conventions, `this` is passed specially, in a way that isn't used for other parameters).

Comment: You can use `std::invoke(&ClassName::Method, instance, args)`

Comment: It is possible that you got confused with the UFCS proposals for c++. Those proposals are never actually included in any standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::mem_fn` is the nearest to what you are asking for:

```
#include <functional>

auto x = std::mem_fn(&ClassName::memberFunctionName);
x(classInstance, arg);
```

If `memberFunctionName()` is overloaded, you will have to use a cast to select an overload:

```
// selects void ClassName::overloadedMemberFunc(int)
auto y = std::mem_fn( (void(*)(int)) &ClassName::overloadedMemberFunc);
```

However, the usual way to accomplish this is with pointers to member functions

```
(obj.*&Cls::func)(arg);

ReturnType (*p)(ArgType) = &Cls::func;
(obj.*p)(arg);

Cls *p2 = &obj;
(p2->*p)(arg);
```

The parentheses around the object the function names are required because of operator precedence